# What does "blanket selling" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

The U.S. stock market may be worried about a potential rise in interest rates, 
but blanket selling in anticipation of a move by the Federal Reserve—which is 
widely expected to happen before the end of the year—isn't the right move for 
investors, according to a Goldman Sachs research report released Wednesday.

source: [www.marketwatch.com](http://www.marketwatch.com/story/these-6-financials-could-bet-the-best-bets-if-interest-rates-rise-says-goldman-2016-09-14)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Blanket](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/blanket)*** in the case you mention is used to refer to an activity carried out by a wide number of people, in the specific case the selling of stocks by the a wide variety of investors:

> - (modifier) applying to or covering a wide group or variety of people, conditions, situations, etc: ***blanket insurance*** against loss, injury, and theft.

(Collins Dictionary)

See also "[blanket reccomendation](http://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/blanketrec.asp)" from Investopedia.

Comment: Still  a typo - re**c**ommendation

Comment: Or the indiscriminate selling of all stocks in a portfolio in anticipation of events that will affect the value of stocks in general, rather than a particular stock or stocks in a particular industry.